# Send binary stream to browser and then update the page

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page with a text status and a button to export an Excel file. When the user clicks the button, I want to generate the file on the fly and return it to the client as binary stream. Then I want to change the text status to show success/failure.

So far I can generate and send the file no problem, but obviously the statuses don't get displayed, since the server response was used to send the file and not a new updated page with the new status.

I'm not sure what's the cleanest way to approach this. I can think of something but is it the best way:

- User clicks on button.
- File is generated and saved as a stream in the session.
- Statuses are updated and the page with the new statuses is returned to the client.
- A piece of Javascript on the page opens a 3rd party page which retrieves the saved stream from the session.

What do you think? It feels MacGyver-ish to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around.  Have the button's request send the file as a normal response, and then pull the session's status in the background on another connection.  If you use AJAX, you can update the existing page dynamically via its DOM, a UpdatePanel, etc.  Otherwise, open a separate window that requests a status page and runs a timer to refresh the page periodically.

Comment: If I send the file as a normal response to the button click, could I use AJAX from the server-side code to ask the client-side page to reload itself? I'm not familiar with AJAX, but is there a functionality like this?

Comment: No.  AJAX is client-code code, it sends requests to the server using a separate connection.  If you have the server send the binary file in reply to the user's request, the existing page is not changed, so it is free to continue running its client-side scripts as needed.  If AJAX is enabled, the page can use timers to send status requests.  Otherwise, open a new window and use a <meta> refresh timer instead.